# Telegram API, Send Multiple Photo

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем доброе утро! Не могу разобраться как отправить несколько фотографий одним сообщением. Хелп ребята.

Есть класс, у которого в конструктуре `__init__` есть переменная `self.multiPhoto = []`. В методе я заполняю эту переменную вот так:
`for img in item['attachments']:
    self.multiPhoto.append(img['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url'])`

Из доки я понял, что нужно юзать метод `sendMediaGroup` с параметрами `chat_id` и `media`. В `media` должна быть `json` строка.

Вот как я это делаю:

`media = json.dumps({'type':'photo','media':self.multiPhoto,'caption':self.text})`

И вот так отправляю сообщение в телеграмм: `self.telegram.send_media_group(self.chanel,media)`

Вот ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать правильно, чтоб заработало? Хелп, плиз)

Comment: Попробуйте это: `media = json.dumps(str({'type':'photo','media':self.multiPhoto,'caption':self.text}))` вместо вашего объявление `media = json.dumps({'type':'photo','media':self.multiPhoto,'caption':self.text})`

Comment: Не, не получается

Comment: добавьте пример словаря `item` пжл